# Elements in common for each two elements in first column dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new with Pandas. I have the following dataframe.

```html
Group           type

    G1          a1
    G1          a2
    G1          a3
    G2          a2
    G2          a1
    G3          a1
    G4          a1
    G5          a4
    G5          a1
```

And I would like to obtain for each couple of groups how many "types" they have in common. Something like this:

```html
Group           type  count

    G1          a1
    G1          a2
    G1          a3
    G2          a2
    G2          a1
    G3          a1
    G4          a1
    G5          a4
    G5          a1
    
count: (G1, G2, 2) (Elements in common: a1,a2)
count: (G1, G3, 1) (Elements in common: a1)
count: (G1, G4, 1) (Elements in common: a1)
...
```

Do you have any idea how could I implement this? Is there any function from the pandas library that could guide me into the right direction.

Comment: `count (G1, G2, 2)` ?  You want to write a function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need [`numpy.intersect1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html):

```
import itertools

#get all combinations of Group values
c = list(itertools.combinations(list(set(df['Group'])), 2))

df = df.set_index('Group')

#create list of tuples of intersections and lengths 
L = []
for a, b in c:
    d = np.intersect1d(df.loc[a], df.loc[b]).tolist()
    L.append((a,b, len(d), d))

#new DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(L, columns=['a','b','lens','common'])
print (df)
    a   b  lens    common
0  G2  G4     1      [a1]
1  G2  G1     2  [a1, a2]
2  G2  G3     1      [a1]
3  G2  G5     1      [a1]
4  G4  G1     1      [a1]
5  G4  G3     1      [a1]
6  G4  G5     1      [a1]
7  G1  G3     1      [a1]
8  G1  G5     1      [a1]
9  G3  G5     1      [a1]
```

Comment: Yes was thinking about itertools product but combinations is much better.

Answer (score 0):

Given a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([['G1', 'G1', 'G2', 'G2'], ['a1', 'a2', 'a1', 'a3']]).T
df.columns = ['group', 'type']
```

Then there are two options:

```
df.groupby('type').count()
```

or if you want to know them explicitly:

```
df.groupby(['type', 'group']).count()
```

Thus you can do, e.g.:

```
df1.loc['a1']
```

with output:

```
group
G1
G2
```

Comment: Well assign the values of groupby to `df1` in the code. And the output OP provided it cant be done in this simple way : ). You might come up with better solution with itertools product :)